# UINavigationBar weird color change

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am using a custom color for my UINavigationBars that I set globally (on iOS7) in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [UIColor mainThemeColor]];
```

This works fine, but in two of my screens I see something very odd. When the view appears, I see a dark glow move in from the right, and the color of the bar ends up to be darker than what I set it to. I tried setting the color in `viewDidAppear` et al, but the same thing happens.

I have no idea how this can happen, all my views and viewControllers are set up the same.

Also, when the app is in the background, and I go to the app switching view (with all the miniature screens), the bar for those two screens is completely dark, instead of the theme color.

Has anyone seen this?

EDIT: It has to do with calling `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` on my view controllers.  If I remove that line, then the coloring of the navbar remains correct.  However, in that case, part of my view is hidden.